# How to pass variable to a another php file using ajax onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How can i pass different ids using ajax to a different php file on click so that it can be used there for mysql queries.
I have already used sessions but as i am using while statements for creating divisions so on using sessions it is only passing value of the last div
So any possible way to do it by ajax?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var yourid = "some id";
    $.post("your_file.php", {data: yourid}, function(result){
        $("span").html(result);
    });
});
```

try some google next time...
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp

Comment: what is the diff bw : $("button").click(function(){   vs $("button").on('click',function(){  @Pepo_rasta thank you

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery

```
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"r_pdf_BioChem.php?q="+<?php echo $PHPVAR1 ?>+"&q1="+<?php echo $PHPVAR2;?>
    .
    .
```

or
pass the values of HTML elements in ONCLICK function

for JAVASCRIPT

HTML

```
<input type='button' name='btn1' id='btn1' value='Proceed' onclick='onclick_fun_for_ajax(ele1.value,ele2.value);'>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    function onclick_fun_for_ajax(nmbr,year)
    {


        xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
        if ( xmlHttp == null )
        {
                alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
                return;
        }

        var url="target_php.php";
            url=url+"?q="+nmbr;
            url=url+"&q1="+year;
            url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();

        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;

        xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    function stateChanged()
    {
            var zdivid="fetched_result";
            if ( xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete" )
            {
                    document.getElementById(zdivid).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
            }
    }
    function GetXmlHttpObject()
    {
            var xmlHttp=null;
            try
            {
                    //Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
                    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                    //Internet Explorer
                    try
                    {
                            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch (e)
                    {
                            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
            }
            return xmlHttp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```js
// Init click event
$('#your_button').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();             
      save(); // Function that sends the ajax request
  });
```

```js
function save() {
    var myvar1 = $('div#select_your_datas'),
        myvar2 = $('div#select_your_datas2');
    $.ajax({
            url: 'path/to/php.php', // File that does sql stuff
            type: 'POST',
            data: { myvar1: myvar1, // Before colon is the object property. After the colon is the value
                    myvar2: myvar2 
                   },
            success:function(dataFromAjaxResponse, typeFromAjaxResponse) { 
                alert('ajax success');

            },
            error: function(dataFromAjaxResponse) {
                alert('ajax error');
                console.log(dataFromAjaxResponse);
            }
        });
}
```

```php
<?php
$myvar1 = $_POST['myvar1'];
$myvar2 = $_POST['myvar2'];
// Do your SQL stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you want is a PHP script that handles a request. Like this:

```
// Search.php
$id         = ( isset( $_GET['id'] ) ? $_GET['id'] : null );
$response   = array();

if( !is_null( $id ) && is_numeric( $id ) )
{
        $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id');
        $query->execute( array( "id" => $id ) );

        $response["Error"] = false;
        $response["Users"] = $query->fetchAll();

} else {
    $response["Error"] = true;
    $response["Message"] = "No Id specified or id not numeric.";
}

print json_encode( $response );
```

On your client side code, where you want your ajax to be, you will need a form and a JavaScript method to handle the form, sending it async to the Search.php script. An example could be

```
// SearchForm.php
<form>
    <input type="text" id="IdInput" /> <input type="button" id="searchButton" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $('#searchButton').click(function()
        {
            var query = $('#IdInput').val();

            $.getJSON('/Search.php?id=' + query, function(response)
            {
                if( response.Error == false )
                {
                    console.log( response.Users );
                } else {
                    alert( response.Message );
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```